# Refactoring help for ORA-14300 partitioning key maps to a partition outside maximum permitted number of partitions

Tags: oracle, plsql, refactoring, partitioning, large-data

Last year i inherited a 15 year old / 250K lines of code Oracle system from a colleague who retired. It's been running flawlessly, but yesterday it completely imploded with hundreds of error mails. I quickly narrowed it down to this error:

```
ORA-14300 partitioning key maps to a partition outside maximum permitted number of partitions
```

There's a large number of tables containing tens of billions of rows, all defined like this:

```
create table Form_16202
(
   File_id    number (15) not null
)
partition by range (File_id) interval (1)
(partition P1 values less than (826098))
enable row movement;
```

The File_id is an id created from our organization-wide file-receiving system, which probably wasnt very widely used 15 years ago, but now is. Long story short, yesterday's File_id hit 1874788.

Doing some detective work, i found that oracle allows a max of 1,048,575 potential partitions on a table. Coincidentally, 1874788 - 826098 equals 1,048,690.

It's clear that "partition by range (File_id) interval ( 1 )" is no longer a viable solution. I'm a decent enough Oracle guy, but certainly no expert and Partition Optimization definitely isnt something i've done a lot of.

My first thought is to remake all implicated tables as "partition by list (File_id)" instead, but i lack the experience to foresee if this would cause any change in behaviour or overall performance. We have a test platform, but the sheer amount of data makes creating/running exhaustive test-cases very heavy and time-consuming and so i would prefer having at least a viable plan before starting Indiana Jones levels of adventures.

Hoping some clever people onhere might be able to help.

Comment: Do you really need one partition per file ID? And do you ever drop old partitions? Can you use a larger range, and/or merge existing partitions - maybe older ones?

Comment: Having one partition per file seems excessive. Having a million partitions is definitely excessive. If there are more columns you aren't showing us, then pick a date column (like load date) and re-partition monthly by that date.

Comment: There's a large number of joins including several tables, each holding several hundred million rows. All joins include the partition key. Maybe i can optimize in the future, but for a short term solution, i dont dare change such a core part of the system. There's "only" 2500 partitons on the tables, so that in itself shouldnt be an issue. It's a very important system, so i'm looking for a solution where i only have to change the tables, not the code.

Answer (score 0):

For minimal change without code impacts, repartition with **interval(100)**. That would reduce the # of potential partitions to 1/100th the current max, giving you plenty of time to rethink the partitioning strategy long-term before running into this problem again.

```
CREATE TABLE Form_16202$new
(file_id)
PARTITION BY RANGE (file_id) INTERVAL(100)
(PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (826100))
ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT
PARALLEL (DEGREE 16)
AS
SELECT file_id FROM Form_16202;

-- script out any create any indexes, constraints, etc.. then rename:

ALTER TABLE Form_16202 RENAME TO Form_16202$old;
ALTER TABLE Form_16202$new RENAME TO Form_16202;
```

However, before doing this, you'd better make sure that no user code is doing partition-level operations, such as `EXCHANGE PARTITION`, `TRUNCATE PARTITION`, `MOVE PARTITION`, etc.. or using extended naming syntax { `PARTITION (partition_name)` }, though that's very unlikely with interval partitioning because of the system-generated names. Hopefully your app is agnostic about its partitioning. Also, you mentioned that your app does a lot of joins between similar tables. if that's so, you will want to do the same change to all of them, with the same starting point (e.g. 826100 in this example). If the starting points are different, you won't get partition-wise joins like you do today.

Comment: Thanks, repartitioning with interval 100 (or just 10 i guess) could be a managable short term solution.
I know i have a bunch of code exploration to do, to check for in-code Partitioning Manipulation (i'm mildly optimistic that there isnt any) and various other potential issues. I just prefer having a few good ideas at the ready instead of going in blind.


Havent done a deep dive yet, but all tables seem to be created with the same starting partition (likely the first file_id available when the system was born). And yes i will need to do the same operation on every implicated table.

Comment: But would there be any issues in partitioning by list instead? That would avoid Oracle "locking" potential partitions and only create one for every new file_id.

Comment: You won't want to use list, that's for small, discrete sets of meaningful attributes, usually varchar2, not anything that currently has a thousand plus partitions.

Comment: With CTAS/rename you won't have any locking issues, though you will of course want to make sure that between the start of the CTAS and the rename your app isn't modifying the table, or you could lose data in the process. This is an outage maintenance process. You can do it without kicking the app out if you pre-create the table and pdml insert append file by file, on teh assumption that existing files aren't been changed. Then you just have to ensure there are no more loads between the load insert and the rename. But that requires more complexity and steps.